# How to test a cocoa touch app for the case when the network fails while downloading a file?

Tags: cocoa-touch, testing, networking

My iOS application, among its features, download files from a specific server. This downloading occurs entirely in the background, while the user is working on the app. When a download is complete, the resource associated with the file appears on the app screen.

My users report some misbehavior about missing resources that I could not reproduce. Some side information leads me to suspect that the problem is caused by the download of the resource's file to be aborted mid-way. Then the app has a partially downloaded file that never gets completed.

To confirm the hypothesis, to make sure any fix works, and to test for such random network vanishing under my feet, I would like to simulate the loss of the network on my test environment: the test server is web sharing on my development Mac, the test device is the iOS simulator running on the same Mac.

Is there a more convenient way to do that, than manually turning web sharing off on a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're downloading your file, one possible option would be to set the callback delegate to null halfway through the download.  It would still download the data, but your application would simply stop receiving callbacks.  Although, I don't know if that's how the application would function if it truly dropped the connection.

Another option would be to temporarily point the download request at some random file on an external web server, then halfway though just disconnect your computer from the internet.  I've done that to test network connectivity issues and it usually works.  The interesting problem in your case is that you're downloading from your own computer, so disconnecting won't help.  This would just be so you can determine the order of callbacks within the application when this happens, (does it make any callbacks at all?  In what order?) so that you can simulate that behavior when actually pointed to your test server.

Combine both options together, I guess, to get the best solution.